# Invoke msiexec on remote machine and get 0x80070005 error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-installer, invoke-command

I'm trying to do a script in powershell that install msi files on remote machines in the same domain. When i use Invoke-Command to run simple cmdlets on remote machine everything works fine, but when i try to invoke msiexec i've got this error from msi log

> MSI (c) (50:C4) [10:50:30:962]: Failed to connect to server. Error:
>   0x80070005

function in InstallFunction.ps1 file

```
function ManageMsi {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $msiFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [MsiOperation] $operation,

    [string] $TARGETVDIR,
    [string] $TARGETAPPPOOL = "DefaultAppPoll" ,
    [string] $logPath = $msiFile + ".txt"

)       
begin {}

process {
    try {
        if($operation -eq [MsiOperation]::Install)
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe" `
            -ArgumentList "/i `"$msifile`" /qn /L* `"$logPath`"" -Wait    
        }
        if($operation -eq [MsiOperation]::Uninstall)
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe" `
            -ArgumentList "/x `"$msifile`" /qn /L* `"$logPath`"" -Wait 
        }
        if($operation -eq [MsiOperation]::InstallService)
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe" `
            -ArgumentList "/i `"$msifile`" TARGETVDIR=`"$TARGETVDIR`" TARGETAPPPOOL=`"$TARGETAPPPOOL`" /qn /L* `"$logPath`"" -Wait    
        }   
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message.ToString()
    }
}
end {}
```

}

And code in main script

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
. InstallFunctions.ps1
ManageMsi -msiFile $msiFile -operation InstallService -TARGETVDIR $vdir } -ComputerName $servName
```

Function ManageMsi work fine on local machine.
Thanks for any answers

**Edit**: When i use

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $servName
Enter-PSSession $sesion
```

then in remote machine

```
msiexec /i "SomeSetup.msi" TARGETVDIR="SomeVDir" TARGETAPPPOOL="DefaultAppPoll" /qn /L* logMsiTest.txt
```

I've got this error (sorry about format above)

> T h e   W i n d o w s   I n s t a l l e r   S e r v i c e   c o u l d   n o t   b e   a c c e s s e d .   T h i s   c a n   o c c u r   i f   t h e   W i n d o 
>   w s   I n s t a l l e r   i s   n o t   c o r r e c t l y   i n s t a l l e d .   C o n t a c t   y o u r   s u p p o r t   p e r s o n n e l   f o r   a s s i 
>   s t a n c e .

Comment: Error 0x80070005 means "access is denied". Does your user have the required permissions on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, and both machine is in the same domain

Comment: Can you run the command locally when you log into the remote machine via RDP? Is UAC enabled on the remote machine? If so, what happens if you (temporarily) disable it?

Comment: Command work fine locally. I'm not allowed to disable UAC

Comment: I'm working on XP so there's no UAC

Comment: Perhaps a [2nd-hop problem](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx)? Do you see any helpful information in eventlog or logMsiTest.txt?

Comment: From logMsiTest.txt :
MSI (c) (50:C4) [10:50:30:962]: Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80070005

From eventlog on remote machine :
Event Type: Warning
Event Source: MsiInstaller
Event Category: None
Event ID: 1015
Date:  2013-08-20
Time:  12:27:06
User:  SomeUser
Computer: SomeComputer
Description:
Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80070005

Comment: Hi Asngar, i try to run this command :
`Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer * -Force`

And i got this :
Enable-WSManCredSSP : This Powershell cmdlet is not available on the following platforms: Windows XP and Wind
ows Server 2003.

Comment: Also this doesn't work properly :
`$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName comp -Authentication CredSSP`

Comment: I will try test this on machines with win2k8

Comment: Did you install the [Windows Management Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) on the XP and Server 2003 machines?